# How do I convert a string with a different time zone to a datetime object?

Tags: python, datetime

I understand how to convert a string to a datetime object, but what about a string that has a different time zone? for example "10/07/2011 04:22 CEST"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[EST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EST) can mean two different timezones: European Summer Time, or Eastern Standard Time. So datetime strings such as `08/07/2011 04:22 EST` are ambiguous -- there's no sure-fire way to correctly convert such strings to a timezone-aware datetime.

If you are willing to just make a stab at a possibly correct answer, then 
you can generate a mapping between abbreviations like `EST` and timezone names, make a random choice among the valid timezones, and 
then use that timezone to build a timezone-aware datetime:

```
import dateutil.tz as dtz
import pytz
import datetime as dt
import collections
import random

timezones = collections.defaultdict(list)
for name in pytz.common_timezones:
    timezone = dtz.gettz(name)
    try:
        now = dt.datetime.now(timezone)
    except ValueError:
        # dt.datetime.now(dtz.gettz('Pacific/Apia')) raises ValueError
        continue
    abbrev = now.strftime('%Z')
    timezones[abbrev].append(name) 

date_string, tz_string = '10/07/2011 04:22 CEST'.rsplit(' ', 1)
date = dt.datetime.strptime(date_string, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
print(date)
# 2011-10-07 04:22:00

tz = pytz.timezone(random.choice(timezones[tz_string]))
print(tz)
# Europe/Oslo

date = tz.localize(date)
print(date)
# 2011-10-07 04:22:00+02:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use strptime with a %Z in your format string, but be aware of this note from the Python documentation (http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

"%Z -- If tzname() returns None, %Z is replaced by an empty string. Otherwise %Z is replaced by the returned value, which must be a string. The full set of format codes supported varies across platforms, because Python calls the platform C library’s strftime() function, and platform variations are common."

Can you put the timezone into offset form and use %z instead?

Comment: Neither of those seem to work for me, not sure if I'm doing it wrong.
>>> a = datetime.datetime.strptime('08/07/2011 04:22 +0100','%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %z')
ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %z'

>>> a = datetime.datetime.strptime('08/07/2011 04:22 EST','%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %Z')
ValueError: time data '08/07/2011 04:22 EST' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M %Z'

Comment: Works for me but with the time module >>> time.strptime("30 Nov 2011 PDT", "%d %b %Y %Z")
time.struct_time(tm_year=2011, tm_mon=11, tm_mday=30, tm_hour=0, tm_min=0, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=334, tm_isdst=1)
  but I will try with datetime now.

Comment: WIth datetime.strptime, I get the same problem you do when I use a timezone other than PDT.  This will take more looking into.

Comment: time.time has the same issue. ValueError: time data '30 Nov 2011 PDT' does not match format '%d %b %Y %Z' For me both things only work with GMT which is my computers local time zone. I'm guessing neither of them accept a time zone apart from the local one?

Comment: datetime.strptime probably uses time.strptime internally.  From more reading, it appears neither %z nor %Z are guaranteed to be well supported.  An interesting thread is here: http://bugs.python.org/issue6641.  Where are you getting this date text from?